# how to remove space and include '{' in python print function

Tags: python, whitespace

I want to print a string that includes `{` and I want to remove additional spaces.
For example:

```
print 'Value is {', value, '}'
```

The output will be:

```
Value is { 42 }
```

But I want:

```
Value is {42}
```

I tried

```
print 'Value is {{}}'.format(value)
```

and I got:

```
Value is {}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: use `+` instead of `,` in the print statement, `print 'Value is {'+str(value)+'}'`

Comment: @ZdaR, that will result in error since you cannot concatenate `int` and `str` if value is `int` in this case.

Comment: `print 'Value is {' + str(value) + '}'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double curly braces for a formatted string indicate a literal brace. You'll need a third pair to indicate the formatting interpolation.

```
>>> 'Value is {{{}}}'.format(42)
'Value is {42}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this:

```
>>> print 'Value is {%s}' % value
Value is {42}
```